# using global variables in a python game

Tags: python

I have some code

```
import random
Numbers = ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King")
Types = ("Hearts", "Clubs", "Spades", "Diamonds")

Number = random.choice(Numbers)
Type = random.choice(Types)
Card = Number + " of " + Type

print(Card)
ans = input("h or l?\n")

def second_card():
    Number2 = random.choice(Numbers)
    Type2 = random.choice(Types)
    Card2 = Number2 + " of " + Type2
    if Card2 == Card:
        second_card()

if ans == "h":
    if Number < Number2:
        print(Card2)
    elif Number > Number2:
        print(Card2)
        print("YOUR OUT")
    else:
        print(Card2)
        print("equal")
elif ans == "l":
    if Number > Number2:
        print(Card2)
    elif Number < Number2:
        print(Card2)
        print("YOUR OUT")
    else:
        print(Card2)
        print("equal")
```

this is a simple version of high or low game
however it doesn't work as in the

```
if Number < Number2
```

line it doesn't recognize the variable Number2 were do i put global Number2 as i have tried a few places and they don't work

Comment: Where you have Number = random.choice(Numbers), just add another line that says Number2 = None.  Then just inside "def second_card()", add the line "global Number2"

Comment: Please check your formatting in this question, it's likely misleading us.

Comment: You aren't actually calling the function `second_card()` You might want to call that before proceeding with the rest of the logic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add a `return` statement to your `second_card()` function to return `Number2`, `Type2` and `Card2`. Then call `second_card()` afterwards (which you currently don't do, so neither of these variables can ever be set by that function).

```
def second_card():
    Number2 = random.choice(Numbers)
    Type2 = random.choice(Types)
    Card2 = Number2 + " of " + Type2
    if Card2 == Card:
        return second_card()
    return (Number2, Type2, Card2)

Number2, Type2, Card2 = second_card()
```

---

Alternatively with global variables:

```
Number2, Type2, Card2 = None, None, None

def second_card():
    global Number2, Type2, Card2
    Number2 = random.choice(Numbers)
    Type2 = random.choice(Types)
    Card2 = Number2 + " of " + Type2
    if Card2 == Card:
        second_card()

second_card()
```

Comment: adding on to this question if i wanted to do more numbers for example Card3, Card4, etc in the game. would i be able to have a loop were it repeats the code for next card and cheaking if it is high or low but changes variables Card to Card2 and Card2 to Card3

Comment: It sounds like you should implement a more abstract version of `second_card()`, e.g. `get_card()` which returns a random card. Then add another function `is_higher(card_a, card_b)` to compare two cards for whether card_a is higher than card_b. Then run a loop to compare one card to a list of other cards, where the list can have any size/length.